# style.left will not update

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figureout why ***`note.style.left = (e.clientX - offLeft) + "px";`***
  and ***`note.style.top = (e.clientY - offTop) + "px";`*** will not update themselves.
I've looked at a ton of examples. Some right from stackoverflow. And I've console.log()'d out each of the variables and I can't figure it out.
At first, I thought that the numbers weren't getting subtracted properly because they might have been strings. I did typeof and confirmed they are numbers and the math is proper. I made sure that the style.left could actually set a number by using ***`note.style.left = 25 + "px";`***. So that means I'm accessing the property properly.

I don't know what's happening.  I've spent a few days looking at a few lines of code and loggin, and looking at w3c and it seems to me that the code should work.  It does not lol. I would really appreciate some help.

FYI - I realize that I have not applied mouseup and/or removed the event listeners.  I am trying to get one step at a time working.

```js
var note = document.getElementById("test-note");
var show = document.getElementById("output");

note.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);

function mouseDown(e){
  note.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
}

function mouseMove (e){
  //console.log(e);
  var offLeft = e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft;
  var offTop = e.clientY - e.srcElement.offsetTop;
  note.style.left = (e.clientX - offLeft) + "px";
  note.style.top = (e.clientY - offTop) + "px";
  show.innerHTML = note.style.left;
  //console.log(typeof (e.clientX + "px"));
}
```

```css
#test-note{
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 50px;
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}
#output{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-note">This is my test note</div>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Do you want `#test-note` to be sticky to cursor as expected output?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I would like the element I click on to move with the mouse. Like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/kjwLe9bq/ (I don't understand their code but the example works how I want mine to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the update but the value always being the same.

```
 (e.clientX - offLeft) = (e.clientX - (e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft)) = e.srcElement.offsetLeft;
```

And `e.srcElement.offsetLeft` is equal to the left value you set, so it will keep changing with the same initial value.

You need to change your logic, make the calculation of `offLef/offTop` inside the mousedown handler so it become a constant inside the mousemouve handler. You should also use [`target` instead of `srcElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement)

```js
var note = document.getElementById("test-note");
var show = document.getElementById("output");

note.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
var offLef;
var offTop;

function mouseDown(e){
  note.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
  offLeft = e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft;
  offTop = e.clientY - e.srcElement.offsetTop;
}

function mouseMove (e){
  //console.log(e);
  note.style.left = (e.clientX - offLeft) + "px";;
  note.style.top = (e.clientY - offTop) + "px";;
  show.innerHTML = note.style.left;
  //console.log(typeof (e.clientX + "px"));
}
```

```css
#test-note{
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 50px;
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}
#output{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-note">This is my test note</div>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you tried this code, or if my browser is doing something different, but the element jumps all over rapidly for me.   I appreciate the help but the outcome is pretty different than I expected.

Comment: @JasonG I know it jumps strange. The purpose of my answer wasn't to give the correct behavior as I don't know what you want but to highlight your issue which is the fact that you are using a constant formula. By simply changing the formula it works. Now you need to adjust it to make it like you want ;)

Comment: Sorry @Temani Afif but I guess I'm still confused. What's the difference between using a real number like `var offLeft = e.clientX - 50;` and what is also a number (I checked with typeof) `var offLeft = e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft;`? They should be the same thing. Except that the offsetnumber changes depending on where the mousedown event starts.  Isn't that true? What am I missing here?

Comment: @JasonG you are missing nothing, it's a simple math here, no JS ... your first attempt is always a constant number, that's what I am trying to explain. The udapte is good but the number is the same each time ... Use a pen and paper and expand your formula (like I did in my answer) and you will see the issue

Comment: I've done the math many times through console.log() the math is right. Let's think this through together.
You get the mouses position. You get the left side of the elements position. 
Then, you subtract the elements position from the mouses current position. That's the difference between the edge of the element, and the mouse pointer. 
Finally, I set the new left position to mousesX - theDifference.
This should always be a new number. What do I have wrong?

Comment: @JasonG no, please forget about JS and console.log() ... here is the formula you are using `a - (a - b)` are you convinced that this formula is the same as `b` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your example. [offsetLeft](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetleft.asp) is the left side position of the element. let's say it was 50px. the mouses position is [clientX](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp) . let's say that was 100px;. So what I'm doing is, taking the mouse(100px) subtracting the left(50px) of the elements position, and that should be the difference (50px) between the two. Do we agree on that?

Comment: So, we know the difference. Now how do we determine the new left position? Current mouse position - the difference.  Wherever the mouse moves, you take away the difference and set the left of the element to that new position. I believe this is accurate.  If you see a flaw in this logic, please let me know because I don't see it.

Comment: @JasonG it's easy and simple : you have `offLeft = e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft` then later you have `note.style.left = (e.clientX - offLeft) + "px";` .. we do some basic maths and replace the content of `offLeft` and we will have `note.style.left = (e.clientX - (e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft)) + "px";` ... we do some basic maths and we simplify this formula and we will have `note.style.left = e.srcElement.offsetLeft + "px";`

Comment: are you convinced that at the end you are doing `note.style.left = e.srcElement.offsetLeft + "px";` which is affecting the same value again and again .. the e.clientX is no more here ... your element won't move because there is no dymanic value added, so the issue is math no JS and nothing  ...  did you get it?

Comment: @JasonG your fomula is `c = a - (a - b)` and `a` is dynamic and is the cursor position but the math tell us that at the end `c = b` so `a` is removed

Comment: I truly don't see how `(e.clientX - offLeft) = (e.clientX - (e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft)) = e.srcElement.offsetLeft;` this is true. let's use real numbers. say the mouse enters at 100px `clientX = 100, e.srcElement.offsetLeft = 50;`  or the mouse could enter the element at 150px `clientX = 150, e.srcElement.offsetLeft = 50;` so the difference between the two will change, but e.srcElement.offsetLeft = 50; will stay the same (at least for the first mousemove event);

Comment: sorry but if you really don't see how this is true `(e.clientX - (e.clientX - e.srcElement.offsetLeft)) = e.srcElement.offsetLeft;` I have no more to say ... replace with values and try ... `(100 - (100 - 40)) = 100 - 60 = 40` .. again `(80 - (80 - 40)) = 80 - 40 = 40` and again `(150 - (150 - 40)) = 150 - 110 = 40` ... we always have `40` whataver the other value is (again forget about mouse and JS, it's pure math)

Comment: @JasonG `a - (a - b) = b` as simple as that

Comment: I'm trying to understand this and I appreciate your help.  Sorry, I'm just trying to wrap my head around this.  I see that your math is right.  Don't I have the right idea here? mousex - elementleft is the difference. Then subtract the difference from the new mouse position? Isn't that what I'm doing? Sorry man. I've been racking my brain for hours on this over multiple days. I can't seem to get it.

Comment: I'm not very good at math but I do agree with this now `a - (a - b) = b`

Comment: `Then subtract the difference from the new mouse position?` --> there is no new here, you are using the same value in both formula .. you do `mouseX - elementLef` then you subtract this from the same `mouseX` .. mouseX here is the `a` of my formula and it will go away and only `b` will remain which is `elementLeft`

Comment: I get that. So how do I grab the `mouseX - elementLeft` difference, and still get the new mousex position? in the mousedown event then? So when mousemove happens, at that point, I take the current mouseX and subtract the difference? (just tried and it didn't work..)

Comment: @JasonG in this case don't make them inside the same handler like your are doing ... put the caclulation of offsetL in the mousedown handler so it won't change .. check the update

Comment: That is pretty much what I was looking for thanks! https://codepen.io/Jay33Canada/pen/OBXVWq I have almost the same thing here but it's not working

Comment: I got it working dude! I can't thank you enough man. Thanks for helping me understand why that math was wrong. And realizing that 'a' wasn't changing. And that I needed to find the difference before getting the new 'a'  (in `a - (a - b) = b`) from the mousemove event.  I can't thank you enouogh man. I've been struggling with this for almost two weeks. Much appreciated! I hope you have a good Thanksgiving!